# How to access decorator attributes?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Is it possible to access decorator attributes in Python 3?

For example: is it possible to access `self.misses` after the call to the decorated fibonacci method?

```
class Cache:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}
        self.misses = 0    
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not (args in self.cache):
            self.misses += 1
            self.cache[args] = self.func(*args)
        return self.cache[args]

@Cache    
def fibonacci(n):
    return n if n in (0, 1) else fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)

fibonacci(20)
### now we want to print the number of cache misses ###
```

Comment: `print(fibonacci.misses)`?

Comment: Indeed. that was too easy, thanks. I was thinking that Cache not being instantiated was a problem. I get it now.

Comment: @louic `Cache` __is__ actually instanciated ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you decorate a function (or class, or anything else), you're actually *replacing* the decorated object with the return value of the decorator. That means that this:

```
@Cache    
def fibonacci(n):
    return n if n in (0, 1) else fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    return n if n in (0, 1) else fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)

fibonacci = Cache(fibonacci)
```

Consequently, `fibonacci` is now a `Cache` instance and not a function:

```
>>> fibonacci
<__main__.Cache object at 0x7fd4d8b63e80>
```

So in order to get the number of cache misses, you just need to access `fibonacci`'s `misses` attribute:

```
>>> fibonacci.misses
21
```